# Invert soundsc in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, signals, signal-processing, communication

Does anyone know what is the inverse function of soundsc in matlab.

I'm playing a sound with a my PC microphone using soundsc, and I want to capture it in another PC using the inverse function.

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try wavrecord, it can capture in realtime (http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/wavrecord.html).

Comment: The only problem would be that it won't be in real time. I need to send byte by byte (encoded with a cosine basis).

Comment: I found a new answer after discussing with my colleague so I completely changed this answer!